# Detect if the TIFF image is Horizontal or Vertical - C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, dimensions

Im using WinForms. In my Form i have a picturebox and a next button. I use this picturebox to display tiff images and i use the next button to navigate to the next page. The tiff documents are multipage images. The document I'm trying to view has a horizontal images and a vertical images like the example below. If its horizontal i want to size it (1100, 800), but if its vertical i want to size it (800, 1100). How do i do this? currently this is what i have but its not a good solution.

```
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path_lbl.Text);

        if (img.Height > img.Width)
        {
           pictureBox1.Width = 800;
           pictureBox1.Height = 1300;
        }
        else
        {
           pictureBox1.Width = 1300;
           pictureBox1.Height = 800;
        }
```

I currently use this approach but this doesn't work because if the first image is vertical the if-statement will always execute the first condition `pictureBox1.size(1300 , 800);` With this method, if the next image is horizontal the condition will not ever re-size it horizontally.

**Example Tiff image**

http://www.filedropper.com/verticalandhorizontal

[image]

**Quick Test Code**

```
   using System;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Drawing.Imaging;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Threading;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Demo
{
class TestForm : Form
{
    public TestForm()
    {
        var panel = new Panel { Dock = DockStyle.Top, BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };
        openButton = new Button { Text = "Open", Top = 8, Left = 16 };
        prevButton = new Button { Text = "Prev", Top = 8, Left = 16 + openButton.Right };
        nextButton = new Button { Text = "Next", Top = 8, Left = 16 + prevButton.Right };

        path_lbl = new Label { Text = "", Top = 12, Left = 16 + nextButton.Right };

        panel.Height = 16 + openButton.Height;
        panel.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { openButton, prevButton, nextButton, path_lbl });
        pageViewer = new PictureBox { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom };
        ClientSize = new Size(850, 1100 + panel.Height);
        Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { panel, pageViewer });
        openButton.Click += OnOpenButtonClick;
        prevButton.Click += OnPrevButtonClick;
        nextButton.Click += OnNextButtonClick;
        Disposed += OnFormDisposed;
        UpdatePageInfo();
    }

    private Button openButton;
    private Button prevButton;
    private Button nextButton;
    private PictureBox pageViewer;
    private PageBuffer pageData;
    private int currentPage;
    private Size pageSize;
    public string path;



    private Label path_lbl;

    private void OnOpenButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                Open(dialog.FileName);
            path = dialog.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void OnPrevButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectPage(currentPage - 1);
    }

    private void OnNextButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            //var data = PageBuffer.Open(path,Size= new Size(850,1150));
            SelectPage(currentPage + 1);
            //Debug.WriteLine("Current Size: 1300, 800");

    }

    private void OnFormDisposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pageData != null)
            pageData.Dispose();
    }

    private void Open(string path)
    {
            var data = PageBuffer.Open(path, new Size(1500, 1500));
            pageViewer.Image = null;
            if (pageData != null)
                pageData.Dispose();
            pageData = data;
            SelectPage(0);
    }

    private void SelectPage(int index)
    {
        pageViewer.Image = pageData.GetPage(index);
        currentPage = index;
        UpdatePageInfo();
    }

    private void UpdatePageInfo()
    {
        prevButton.Enabled = pageData != null && currentPage > 0;
        nextButton.Enabled = pageData != null && currentPage < pageData.PageCount - 1;
    }
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new TestForm());
    }
}

class PageBuffer : IDisposable
{
    public const int DefaultCacheSize = 12; //This is how much images it will have in memory

    public static PageBuffer Open(string path, Size maxSize, int cacheSize = DefaultCacheSize)
    {
        return new PageBuffer(File.OpenRead(path), maxSize, cacheSize);
    }

    private PageBuffer(Stream stream, Size maxSize, int cacheSize)
    {
        this.stream = stream;
        source = Image.FromStream(stream);
        pageCount = source.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
        if (pageCount < 2) return;
        pageCache = new Image[Math.Min(pageCount, Math.Max(cacheSize, 5))];
        pageSize = source.Size;
        if (!maxSize.IsEmpty)
        {
            float scale = Math.Min((float)maxSize.Width / pageSize.Width, (float)maxSize.Height / pageSize.Height);
            pageSize = new Size((int)(pageSize.Width * scale), (int)(pageSize.Height * scale));
        }
        var worker = new Thread(LoadPages) { IsBackground = true };
        worker.Start();
    }

    private void LoadPages()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                if (disposed) return;
                int index = Array.FindIndex(pageCache, 0, pageCacheSize, p => p == null);
                if (index < 0)
                    Monitor.Wait(syncLock);
                else
                    pageCache[index] = LoadPage(pageCacheStart + index);
            }
        }
    }

    private Image LoadPage(int index)
    {
        source.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, index);
        return new Bitmap(source, pageSize);
    }

    private Stream stream;
    private Image source;
    private int pageCount;
    private Image[] pageCache;
    private int pageCacheStart, pageCacheSize;
    private object syncLock = new object();
    private bool disposed;
    private Size pageSize;

    public Image Source { get { return source; } }
    public int PageCount { get { return pageCount; } }
    public Image GetPage(int index)
    {
        if (disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException(GetType().Name);
        if (PageCount < 2) return Source;
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            AdjustPageCache(index);
            int cacheIndex = index - pageCacheStart;
            var image = pageCache[cacheIndex];
            if (image == null)
                image = pageCache[cacheIndex] = LoadPage(index);
            return image;
        }
    }

    private void AdjustPageCache(int pageIndex)
    {
        int start, end;
        if ((start = pageIndex - pageCache.Length / 2) <= 0)
            end = (start = 0) + pageCache.Length;
        else if ((end = start + pageCache.Length) >= PageCount)
            start = (end = PageCount) - pageCache.Length;
        if (start < pageCacheStart)
        {
            int shift = pageCacheStart - start;
            if (shift >= pageCacheSize)
                ClearPageCache(0, pageCacheSize);
            else
            {
                ClearPageCache(pageCacheSize - shift, pageCacheSize);
                for (int j = pageCacheSize - 1, i = j - shift; i >= 0; j--, i--)
                    Exchange(ref pageCache[i], ref pageCache[j]);
            }
        }
        else if (start > pageCacheStart)
        {
            int shift = start - pageCacheStart;
            if (shift >= pageCacheSize)
                ClearPageCache(0, pageCacheSize);
            else
            {
                ClearPageCache(0, shift);
                for (int j = 0, i = shift; i < pageCacheSize; j++, i++)
                    Exchange(ref pageCache[i], ref pageCache[j]);
            }
        }
        if (pageCacheStart != start || pageCacheStart + pageCacheSize != end)
        {
            pageCacheStart = start;
            pageCacheSize = end - start;
            Monitor.Pulse(syncLock);
        }
    }

    void ClearPageCache(int start, int end)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            Dispose(ref pageCache[i]);
    }

    static void Dispose<T>(ref T target) where T : class, IDisposable
    {
        var value = target;
        if (value != null) value.Dispose();
        target = null;
    }

    static void Exchange<T>(ref T a, ref T b) { var c = a; a = b; b = c; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (disposed) return;
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            disposed = true;
            if (pageCache != null)
            {
                ClearPageCache(0, pageCacheSize);
                pageCache = null;
            }
            Dispose(ref source);
            Dispose(ref stream);
            if (pageCount > 2)
                Monitor.Pulse(syncLock);
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to double check that part. @TaW

Comment: The problem is that the code in `Next_btn_click` method is NOT executed for the first image. You should extract the code into separate method and call it from `Open_btn_Click` instead of `RefreshImage()`

Comment: can you give me an example @Euphoric

Comment: I am having trouble understanding exactly what you are trying to achieve with the form, so this suggestion might be wide of the mark. Have you tried setting the PictureBox's SizeMode to Zoom and not resizing the images? Then you simply make the picturebox fit the form and everything else is automatic.

Comment: The picturebox shows multipage tiff images. These multipage images documents are vertical and horizontal like in the example link i just put up. The problem is that i set my picturebox dimension to (800,1100) - the issue with a set dimension is that it makes horizontal images look verticle. I did this however in the mean time because i couldn't figure out the right way to do it. I wanted the picturebox to automatically know between horizontal and vertical when you click on the next button, depending on the tiff image showing. @Ulric

Comment: @taji01 - The Zoom setting removes the need for resizing. A landscape/portrait image will look correct automatically; you do not need to change the dimensions. _"I wanted the picturebox to automatically know between horizontal and vertical when you click on the next button."_ - yes, that is what Zoom does. Try it and see. :)

Comment: I do have it set to zoom, if you copy and paste this code you'll see what i mean @Ulric

Comment: This of course entirely depends on how the source material was placed on the scanner, the Image.Width/Height does not help you.  If there is no reliable metadata in the tiff file that records the orientation then you'd better rely on the user's eyes.  Make it easy to rotate the image with a single click.

Comment: When I use `(windows-photo-viewer)` to view the sample .tif image the app recognizes that the first page is vertical and the 2nd page is horizontal. The problem is within my code. @HansPassant

Comment: Sure, I don't (think) I see it checking for the Orientation tag.  Google "c# read tiff orientation tag".

Comment: @taji01 Well - this doesn't really answer your question, but it would resolve the problem you are having... My suggestion is: unless you have a very specific need to resize the form...don't. Leave the SizeMode at Zoom and let the user decide the size of the form. Simply maximising the form will provide the optimum form size for viewing documents, whatever their orientation. Hope that gives you food for thought. :)  _(p.s. I think there is a bug in your code. I got strange results when using a 5 page TIFF.)_